# /home/username/desktop not recognized: "No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, directory, home-directory

I'm new to Ubuntu within the past couple of months.

I'm working to get some color profiles uploaded to `/usr/share/color/icc` by way of copying a file to that directory from off my desktop. The issue I'm running into is that all of the standard directories nested under `/home/` (including desktop, documents, downloads, etc) are not getting recognized as such, prompting me to get the error message `no such file or directory` anytime I try to access them through terminal.

I understand in theory how to get the folder copied between profiles, but in practice I don't know why everything under my `/home/` directory is not getting recognized as a directory in terminal. Once I get past that, getting the color profiles copied over should be straight forward.

I'm thinking that it may have something to do with how the home directory is structured but I don't want to mess with too much at the risk of making the problem worse by barking up the wrong tree.

Any advice?

Comment: Try /home/user/Desktop. Note the capital D.

Comment: If you're more familiar with Windows, you might be more used to case-insensitive filenames, but on Linux, all filenames are case-sensitive.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Check the directories list in your `~/` user directory:

`ls ~/` or `ls /home/username/`

Then make sure, you have `Desktop` directory in that list. I think, you just need to use capital `D` in your command. Try `/home/username/Desktop` instead.